# Using field in database security rule that is stored in the data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase database with the following structure

[image]

I want to define a database rule where authenticated users can read the data only where authenticated user's id is equal to `userId` defined in the data.
How can i define this rule?

I have tried defining a rule as shown below but id didn't work. It doesn't allows any read operation

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid == root.child('orders').child('userId').val()",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This is how i am making a `GET` request to firebase's REST api

```
axios.get(`/orders.json?auth=${firebaseAuthToken}`)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                dispatch(fetchOrdersSuccess(Object.values(response.data)));
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchOrdersError(error.message));
        });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the database query that doesn't work the way you expect with these rules.  Your question should be clear which node should be readable if the current user ID matches the userId child in the database.  It might be helpful to review the documentation to see how to use wildcards in nested children: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Comment: `orders` is the root node and i want to read the child nodes of the `orders` node. I am using rest api of the firebase and making a `GET` request along with `auth` token. Each immediate child node of `orders` node is a single order

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the exact query, in whatever way you're making it?  Rules are meaningless without queries to go with them - rules should always be matched with intended queries that are expected to either succeed or fail.

Comment: Are you expecting the security rules to filter out only those orders that are tagged as with userId as a child in the order?  That's not going to work, because [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).  Your query should include any filters for the children you want, and your rules should be constructed to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

try the following rule for reading orders

```
{
  "rules": {
    "orders": {
      "$orderId": {
        ".read": "data.child('userId').val() == auth.uid",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```